# filter_has_var function

Tags: php, filter

I was having trouble trying to make this function work for ages. Before, I was doing

```
if ( !filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'email') ) {
    code here etc.
}
```

and this never worked though is the correct format for how the function should be set up. [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-has-var.php)

Then after playing about with it trying to make it function, i changed 'email' to '$email' and this did the trick. So, now I'm confused, is this a glitch or is my code at the top incorrect?

Comment: You want `true` or `false` in your if condition cause I'm confused by your `!` operator in your condition ?

Comment: Is your post an actual post? or did you create the array before your ran that?

Comment: it is an actual post sent from a form by a separate php script

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{ 
   //Your Code here for valid email...
} 
else
{
   //Your Code here for invalid email...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Through this example i think you can better understand

```
if ( !filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'email') ) {
    echo "Email Not Found";
} else {
    echo "Email Found";
}
```

Output

```
    localhost/nanhe/test.php?email=1 //Email Found
    localhost/nanhe/test.php?email //Email Found
    http://localhost/nanhe/test.php //Email Not Found
```

Consider on second example
http://localhost/nanhe/test.php

```
$_GET['email']="info@nanhe.in";
if ( !filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'email') ) {
    echo "Email Not Found";
} else {
    echo "Email Found";
}
```

But output will be Email Not Found